# Преобразовать файл во множество файлов того же формата

Tags: perl

В общем у меня есть задача:
Несколько  десятков  отправителей  пишут  письма  в  Яндекс. Их письма  попадают  в  файл  в формате Unix mailbox. Это обычный текстовый файл,  длина  строк  не  превышает  1000 байт, письма следуют одно за другим. Пример  файла  прилагается  (unix.mailbox).  Признак  начала письма --  строка,  начинающаяся  на  слово  From  ,  сразу  за которым следует 1  пробел,  сразу за которым следует e-mail отправителя, сразу за которым следует  пробел  и  какая-то  дополнительная  информация.  Писем очень  много,  некоторые  из  них  могут  иметь большой объем. Объем входного
 файла может составлять много гигабайт. С другой стороны, кол-во разных отправителей не превышает 100.

Нужно  написать  программу  на  Perl, которая преобразует этот файл во множество  файлов  того же формата, по 1 файлу на каждого отправителя,  все письма одного и того же отправителя должны быть в одном файле. При написании  программы  учесть:

1)  объем  RAM  ограничен,  поэтому не нужно хранить в памяти "лишних"  структур  и  данных,  без которых можно обойтись;

2) открытие файла -- очень дорогая операция, поэтому каждый файл должен открываться/закрываться только 1 раз;

3) в программе нельзя использовать сторонние модули;

4)  решение  ожидается  в виде одного относительно короткого файла (не  более  примерно 50 строк на Perl). Не нужно усложнять решение каким-то  дополнительным функционалом, проверками данных и т.п.

Соотвутствующую литературу читал и продолжаю читать, но пока всё равно сложновато. На форуме нашёл следующие советы:

1. Для решения достаточно 4 переменных (хэш, два стринга(один с именем файла) и $1)
2. Алгоритм решения должен быть примерно таким: 1. Открыть файл. 2. Читать его построчно 3. Если строка - по регексу, то вычленяем отправителя 4.Пишем эту же строку $_ в файл для данного отправителя.(создаем файл, если нужно) 5. Возвращаемся к п.3 6. Закрываем файлы. Есть [вариант кода](http://www.cyberforum.ru/perl/thread311370.html)(не мой), но он не совсем корректный.
    В связи со всем этим вопрос: как решить? не требую готового кода, но хотелось бы понять некоторые моменты: какие именно данные в каких переменных должны храниться? Каков механизм вывода данных из файла, чтобы он открывался только один раз? Зачем используется конструкция ~s/^From .+? //; в приведённом выше коде? Каким образом должен вычленяться отправитель? вопросов много, но это основные)

Заранее извиняюсь за неточную постановку вопросов или неправильное использование терминов, я по специальности экономист, и вот возникла необходимость в программировании. Заранее спасибо, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Взаимоисключающие параграфы детектед :) Или до 100 файлов открытых держать, или переоткрывать каждый раз. Скорее первое — не так уж много памяти, зато нет лишних вызовов open. Так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

```
use strict;
use IO::File;

my %handle;
my $to;
while (<>) {
    if (/^From ([^ ]+)/) {
        $to = $1;

        unless (exists $handle{$to}) {
            $handle{$to} = IO::File->new(">> $to.mbx");
        }
    }
    if ($to) {
        $handle{$to}->print($_);
    }
}
foreach ( values %handle ) {
    $_->close;
}
```

Если нет желания использовать IO::File, без него можно обойтись:

```
use strict;
my %handle;
while (<>) {
    if (/^From ([^ ]+)/) {
        open( $handle{$1}, ">> $1.mbx") unless (exists $handle{$1});
        select( $handle{$1} );
    }
    print $_;
}
close($_) foreach ( values %handle );
```

Comment: спасибо большое! буду сидеть разбирать, что откуда и зачем)

Comment: Первый вариант более прост для понимания, второй использует не очень понятный синтаксис и запутанную функцию `select` которая по-разному работает при разном кол-ве параметров

Comment: А ведь в тексте письма также может быть строка, которая будет отвечать шаблону `/^From /`. Так что код может работать не корректно на некоторых данных.

Answer (score 0):

> При написании программы учесть:...skip...

Вам реальную задачу решать или учебная разминка для мозгов с виртуальными требованиями?

1. "объем RAM ограничен" -> добавьте памяти, она нынче дешева.
2. "открытие файла -- очень дорогая операция" -> пруфлинк?
3. "в программе нельзя использовать сторонние модули" -> религия? и lib какой версии perl тогда рассматривается как corelib ?
4. " в виде одного относительно короткого файла" -> ммм... no comments. хотя нет, лучше уж тогда однострочник требуйте, еще короче будет.

кАроче определитесь с ожиданиями для начала, как perl-овый программист я бы за Вашу задачку не взялся бы. Даже за денежку :)

Comment: согласен, условия дурацкие) но это учебная разминка для мозгов с какими-то вымышленными требованиями) кстати как раз при приёме на работу perl-программистом на самом начальном уровне)
а если бы я всё же вам предложил решить задачу, пусть даже и за денежку?)

Comment: perl-программист с модулефобией - бессмысленный артефакт культа "это сделано не у нас".
Я себя к таким не отношу, так что на таких условиях не играю.

Вот если мы будем оценивать задачу по эффективности решения, да еще конкретизируем платформу и версию perl - то можно подумать :)

Comment: ситауция такова: мне прислали эту задачу по e-mail, как вступительный тест при приёме на работу perl-программистом. В объявлении указывалось "базовое знание perl" - оказалось вот такую бяку надо решить.
Я так понимаю, версию можно брать любую, единственное - чтобы хоть как-нибудь решение соответствовало условиям. 
может быть вы скажете какие-нибудь свои контакты? И там уже что-нибудь решим)

Comment: МММ... хмм... начнем с того, что 
"кол-во разных отправителей не превышает 100." + "объем RAM ограничен" + "открытие файла -- очень дорогая операция" исключает корректное решение.
У вас или 100 открытых файлов будет висеть, что памяти выжрет больше всех структур вместе взятых, да и управлять таким пуллом открытых хендлеров - брррр... или все же нужно открываться на запись каждый раз.
Так что я бы Вам помог, но... а РАБОТАЬ-то вы как будете? задачка дурацкая, но довольно простая.
Гугль меня знает, у него спросите :)

Comment: Например на GFS и аналогичной FS open достаточно дорогая операция

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{ $/ = "From " } print "'$_'"; m#(\S+)# or next; exists ($hash{$1}) or open $hash{$1}, "> $1"; $hash{$1}->print ("From $_");'
```

остальное за свой счет

Comment: Для чего нужен `print "'$_'"` ?

Может следует заменить `$hash{$1}->print ("From $_");` на `print $hash{$1} $/, $_;` что-бы не создавать еще одну достаточно большую строку ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $out_file = 'unknow.txt';

open WRITE, ">>", $out_file or die "Can't create file $out_file";

while (<>) {

    if (/^From ([^ ]+) /) {

        print WRITE "--------------------------------\n"; ## you can delete this string
        $out_file=$1.".txt";
        #### when you open new handler in same name, the last closed automaticaly 
        open WRITE, ">>", $out_file or die "Can't create file $out_file";
    }
    print WRITE;
}
close WRITE;
```

Все так как Вы хотели.  Будет создать email.txt файлы

Comment: у вас дескриптор переоткрывается, да ещё и без закрытия... ой что будет... провалите вы подобное собеседование с таким кодом.

Comment: Ничего не будет не беспокойтесь :)) . Дескриптор открывается для одного файла и закрывается автоматически, когда опять открывается для следуюшего файла (это то же самое как закрить написав close WRITE ). Скажем так, если исходный файл 3 Гб это займет менше 2 мин., фактически чуть больше чем время копирования (кстати у меня  2 Гб Ram).Вообщем работает оно нормально и  не тратит ни каких лишних ресурсов можете сами убедится.